# SFML Trouble CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I am using the latest version of SFML 2.4. I have a problem. I linked the SFML to my Codeblocks, however, I am getting errors such as:

> D:\sfml-release_Sources\SFML\src\SFML\Graphics\RenderTarget.cpp|106|undefined reference to `glClearColor@16'|.

I do not know what to do.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how are u linking the library? add more info

Comment: I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vt0CiMGzBo8

Answer (score 0):

I think you link it staticly, in this case you must link all dependencies! OpenGl(which contain "glClearColor" also) as example